# Dojo: Can't update drop down list after adding a new group

Tags: dojo, drop-down-menu

I've been playing around with IBM's tutorial at this link.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/tutorials/wa-dojotoolkit/section6.html

I've done very well so far, but I can't seem to get the drop down list to populate the new group entry. Even the original code isn't working.

```
    //Refresh the data store for the groups dropdown (in case groups added, edited or deleted)
function refreshGroupDropDown() {
    var theStore = dijit.byId("edit_contact_group").store;
    theStore.close();
    theStore.url = "data/groups.php";
    theStore.fetch();
}
```

Thanks!

Update: Still having trouble. I tried this below and still nothing. The function refreshGroupDropDown() is called when the user opens the edit contact windows or new contact window.

```
    //Refresh the data store for the groups dropdown (in case groups added, edited or deleted)
function refreshGroupDropDown() {
    var new_store = new ItemFileReadStore({url: 'data/groups.php' , clearOnClose: true});
    var theStore = dijit.byId("edit_contact_group");
    theStore.store = new_store;
    theStore.close();
    theStore.fetch();

}

    //Clears the "Edit Contact" form, sets it up for adding a new contact
function newContact() {
    var contact = contactsGrid.selection.getSelected()[0];
    refreshGroupDropDown();
    dojo.byId("edit_contact_real_id").value = "";
    dojo.byId("edit_contact_id").value = "[NEW]";
    dijit.byId("edit_contact_group").reset();
    dijit.byId("edit_contact_first_name").reset();
    dijit.byId("edit_contact_last_name").reset();
    dijit.byId("edit_contact_email_address").reset();
    dijit.byId("edit_contact_home_phone").reset();
    dijit.byId("edit_contact_work_phone").reset();


    dijit.byId("editContactDialog").set("title", "New Contact");
    dijit.byId("editContactDialog").show();
}

    //Process the adding of a new group to the database
function doNewGroup(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    dojo.byId("new_group_ajax").value = "1";
    if(this.isValid()) {
        dojo.xhrPost({
            form: this.domNode,
            handleAs: "json",
            load: function(data) {
                if(data.success) {
                    okDialog.set("title","Group created successfully");
                    okDialogMsg.innerHTML = "The group <strong>"+data.name+"</strong> was created successfully.";

                    groupsStore.newItem({"id":data.id.toString(),"name":data.name}, {"parent": groupsModel.root, "attribute":"groups"});
                    groupsStore.save();

                    newGroupDialog.hide();
                    okDialog.show();
                }
                else {
                    okDialog.set("title","Error creating group");
                    okDialogMsg.innerHTML = data.error;
                    okDialog.show();
                }
            },
            error: function(error) {
                okDialog.set("title","Error creating group");
                okDialogMsg.innerHTML = error;
                okDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps! I'm a beginner so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! The issue was with the index.html. The input tag for the groups drop-down list looks like this

```
<input dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" name="move_contact_new" store="groupsStore" searchAttr="name" query="{type:'node'}" id="move_contact_new" required="true" style="margin-bottom: 6px" />
```

The query attribute was never set correctly. Once I deleted query="{type:'node'}" the groups re-populate after adding, editing, or deleting groups.

A beginner answer for a beginner question.

Hope this can help any beginners out there.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've posted, the only problem I see is with the line var `theStore = dijit.byId("edit_contact_group").store;`because it doesn't acutally create a dataStore.  You need to make sure you also include something like `` `var edit_contact_group = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore(); ``or an equivalent.  Othewise, have you connected the refreshGroupDropDown() function to the appropriated event ('onclick' or whatever) using dojo.connect()?  Have you loaded the function refreshGroupDropDown() using dojo.ready?  ie. `dojo.ready(function(){refreshGroupDropDown();});`Those are always the first things that come to mind...